# How to match private struct types using Ginkgo and Gomega?

Tags: go, ginkgo, gomega

Assume that I have a function called `GetQueue` with GoLang and depends on the configuration, it would return different types of queue implementations.

```
func GetQueue(config string) *service.Queue {
switch(config):
case "A":
  return &QueueA.NewQueue{...}
case "B":
  return &QueueB.NewQueue{...}
...
}
```

The `service.Queue` is an interface. And both `QueueA` and `QueueB` are implementations for this interface. The QueueA.go looks like:

```
type service struct {
...
}

function NewService() *service.Queue {
  return &service{}
}
```

I'd like to write a unit test for the `GetQueue` function (which is defined outside of the `service` package) and I would like to verify the returned types are as expected. However, both `QueueA.sevice` and `QueueB.service` are private structs. So how can I verify the returned types are the expected ones?

Comment: White box testing, test inside the package!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.Is `service.Queue`'s type interface{}? Are `return &QueueA.NewQueue{...}` inside `GetQueue` and `NewService()` inside QueueA.go the same function?

Comment: This code makes no sense. NewService isn't called anywhere and its return type doesn't match what it actually returns. Also, `function` isn't a keyword in Go. Try to make an example that accurately represents your real code, otherwise it's hard to see what your actual problem is.

Comment: @SpiderShrimp Sorry, I did't make it clear enough. I've revised my questions a bit.

Comment: @Peter  Sorry, I did't make it clear enough. I've revised my questions a bit.